# Change div position

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have 20 divs on page which looks like tile side by side. I want to move these divs place (on live page) by changing jquery Mansory code. For example:

```
<div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div> <div>4</div> <div>5</div> <div>6</div>
```

I have coded above thing which displays content in below manner (with help of css - float) :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

what script or css without changing HTML structure will help me to show content in below structure:-

1 2  7  8  13 14 
3 4  9 10  ... 
5 6 11 12
can any one help me with this please.

Comment: You can use `jquery-ui` libraries.

Comment: are you looking for sorting kind of things? or using css do you want to change the position?

Comment: I want sorting div automatically :)

Comment: Use jQuery Isotope and apply the shuffle method to randomise your divs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this cool jquery plugin - http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

From the site: Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason fitting stones in a wall.

Cheers!

EDIT: Try [this](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/category-rows.html) Isotope plugin
 - arranges elements into rows based on their category.

You can categorize the divs and let the plugin sort accordingly. The above link rearranges the divs according to their class names.

Comment: I'm trying to edit masonry code, that's the reason why i asked this question

Comment: masonry sort div fit by their weight & height but not follow structure like that

Comment: can you please post some code so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: thank you maybe I'll find something help myself by Isotype plugin. Then I post it later

Answer (score 0):

use it to do to all...

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <html>
       <head>
          <style>
          .Text{
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif,'Times New Roman';
            font-size: 9pt;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #666;
            text-decoration: none;
          }

          .alertsBoxTitle{
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif,'Times New Roman';
            font-size: 9pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
          .alertsBox{
            background: #ECF1F9;
            border: 1px #a1bcdf solid;
          }
          body{
           overflow:hidden;
          }
          </style>

          <script language="javascript">
          // browser detection
          var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
          var is_major = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
          var is_minor = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);

          var is_nav  = ((agt.indexOf('mozilla')!=-1) && (agt.indexOf('spoofer')==-1)
                      && (agt.indexOf('compatible') == -1) && (agt.indexOf('opera')==-1)
                      && (agt.indexOf('webtv')==-1) && (agt.indexOf('hotjava')==-1));
          var is_nav4 = (is_nav && (is_major == 4));
          var is_nav6 = (is_nav && (is_major == 5));
          var is_nav6up = (is_nav && (is_major >= 5));
          var is_ie     = ((agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) && (agt.indexOf("opera") == -1));

          var dragapproved=false
          var z,x,y
          var maxleft,maxtop,maxright,maxbottom;

          function setdragBounds()
          {
              // you can set the bounds of the draggable area here
              maxleft = 10;
              maxtop = 10;
              maxright = document.body.clientWidth - 10;
              maxbottom = document.body.clientHeight - 100;
          }

          function move(e)
          {
               var tmpXpos = (!is_ie)? temp1+e.clientX-x: temp1+event.clientX-x;
               var tmpYpos = (!is_ie)? temp2+e.clientY-y : temp2+event.clientY-y;
               if (dragapproved)
               {
                  z.style.left = tmpXpos;
                  z.style.top = tmpYpos;

                  if (tmpXpos < maxleft)
                      z.style.left = maxleft;

                  if (tmpXpos > maxright)
                      z.style.left = maxright;

                  if (tmpYpos < maxtop)
                      z.style.top = maxtop;
                  if (tmpYpos > maxbottom)
                      z.style.top = maxbottom;

                  return false
               }
          }

          function drags(e)
          {
                 if (!(is_ie)&&!(!is_ie)) return

                 var firedobj=(!is_ie)? e.target : event.srcElement
                 var topelement=(!is_ie)? "HTML" : "BODY"

                 while (firedobj.tagName!=topelement && firedobj.className!="drag" && firedobj.tagName!='SELECT' && firedobj.tagName!='TEXTAREA' && firedobj.tagName!='INPUT' && firedobj.tagName!='IMG')
                 {
                     // here you can add the elements that cannot be used for drag . using their class name or id or tag names
                     firedobj=(!is_ie)? firedobj.parentNode : firedobj.parentElement
                 }

                 if (firedobj.className=="drag")
                 {
                     dragapproved = true
                     z = firedobj
                     var tmpheight = z.style.height.split("px")
                     maxbottom = (tmpheight[0])?document.body.clientHeight - tmpheight[0]:document.body.clientHeight - 20;

                     temp1 = parseInt(z.style.left+0)
                     temp2 = parseInt(z.style.top+0)
                     x = (!is_ie)? e.clientX: event.clientX
                     y = (!is_ie)? e.clientY: event.clientY
                     document.onmousemove = move

                     return false
                 }
          }

          document.onmousedown=drags
          document.onmouseup=new Function("dragapproved=false")
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="Dialog" style="width:316px;height:119px;max-width:316px;position:relative;top:50px;left:140px; z-index:1000;" class="drag">
        <table width="100%" style="width:315px;height:119px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="alertsBox" id="dialog_table">
          <tr style="cursor:move">
            <td class="alertsBoxTitle notselectable" colspan="2" align="left" height="21" style="cursor:move;background-color:#32426F">Drag Me</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2" height="5"> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
              <table width="97%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' align="center">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' colspan="2" class="Text">this div can be placed any where</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign='top' colspan="2" align="center"><br/><input type="button" value="Ok"/></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://mukhesh.mywapblog.com/category/java-script-27/1.xhtml